# How to enable a user in AD via LDAP?

Tags: java, active-directory, ldap

I'm trying to create an user in AD via Java/LDAP program and the user that is getting created is always disabled. When I tried to set the 'userAccountControl' t0 '512', it is giving me the following error:

javax.naming.OperationNotSupportedException: [LDAP: error code 53 - 0000052D: SvcErr: DSID-031A0FBC, problem 5003 (WILL_NOT_PERFORM), data 0

1) I don't think it's an issue with SSL as I'm able to successfully connect through SSL port and do other operations like modify password etc.

2) I'm also doing the UTF-16 encoding and that is why I'm able to modify the password successfull

Hope to get a response soon.

Thanks ,
antony

Comment: Possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1073643/adding-ldap-entries-using-jndi

Comment: Can you show your code please

Comment: If an account is created without a password, it will be disabled automatically.  You can not enable the account until a password is set or you modify the userAccountControl so that a password is not required.

Comment: Code would be useful, but usually this is because the user doesn't have a password.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I'm setting the password also while creating the user. Here is the code:

Comment: Is your question still valid ? where do you post the code ?

Answer (score 2):

The error you get (`0000052D`) corresponds to the following error message from winerror.h:

```
//
// MessageId: ERROR_PASSWORD_RESTRICTION
//
// MessageText:
//
//  Unable to update the password. The value provided for the new
//  password does not meet the length, complexity, or history
//  requirement of the domain.
//
#define ERROR_PASSWORD_RESTRICTION       1325L
```

From this we can draw the conclusion that your AD has password policy set, which is preventing the user from being created. You have the options here - first to try setting password via LDAP (this requires 128 bit SSL or TLS connection) and second to set the PASSWD_NOTREQD flag (32) in userAccountControl.

Answer (score 0):

When I saw this problem, it turned out my encoding wasn't quite right.  You need to wrap the string password in quotes before encoding:

```
final byte[] adEncodedPassword = ("\"" + password + "\"").getBytes("UTF-16LE");
```

reference: http://encounteringidm.com/will_not_perform-error-from-ad-on-password-change-using-java/